# Best practise for sluggification of certain characters

Tags: slug, slugify

So, let's take, for example, the following sentence:

```
Chandra Source Catalog Release 2.0
```

I've run this through various `string.to_slug()` and `sluggify(string)` methods on different platforms and systems. The outcome is always the following:

```
chandra-source-catalog-release-20
```

Which to me seems incorrect. How should the above edge case be handled? Preference would be for the following:

```
chandra-source-catalog-release-2_0
```

It feels like it has an obvious answer, but then, nuance. The other time a full stop appears is at the end of a sentence. So, we could have:

```
Chandra Source Catalog Release 2.0.
```

I guess what I am asking is as well, is what is the best practice for handling such version numbers in URL slugs?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I have seen for slugging version numbers, is to keep the `.` there are some outliers, that don't follow this but many of the largest companies will keep the `.`. To stay consistent with other websites I would keep the `.`.

For example, if you look at the newest version of this library:

`https://github.com/rawleyfowler/sluj/releases/tag/1.0.2`

You'll notice github keeps the `.` between version numbers.

`https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/releases/v15.2.0-ee`

Gitlab also does this.

Since `.` falls within the `unreserved` category of [RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) it is okay to keep the `.` in the version numbers for your URI.